# How can i get information about installed programms with SNMP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

I need to get info about installed programms with SNMP on Ubuntu. It should look like: Programm name : date of installation. I will be grateful for the help.

Here is config file:

```
com2sec local   127.0.0.1   comm7
group   avt709v7    any local
view    all included    .1
access avt709v7 ""  any noauth  0   all none    none

syslocation SaintPetercburg
syscontact avt709 Telnov Kustov
```